# Selected child nodes text retrieval not working properly in tree view list

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

In my c# windows application, I have a tree view list box with checkboxes set to true. At runtime my program checks for the nodes of this tree view inside an xml file..In my application I have hidden the parent nodes checkboxes using the code shown below:

```
public const int TVIF_STATE = 0x8;
    public const int TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK = 0xF000;
    public const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
    public const int TVM_SETITEM = TV_FIRST + 63;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);

    public struct TVITEM
    {
        public int mask;
        public IntPtr hItem;
        public int state;
        public int stateMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public String lpszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public int iSelectedImage;
        public int cChildren;
        public IntPtr lParam;

    }

    void tree_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Level == 1)
            HideCheckBox(e.Node.Parent);
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void HideCheckBox(TreeNode node)
    {
        TVITEM tvi = new TVITEM();
        tvi.hItem = node.Handle;
        tvi.mask = TVIF_STATE;
        tvi.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
        tvi.state = 0;
        IntPtr lparam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvi));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvi, lparam, false);
        SendMessage(this.taskslctor_treeview.Handle, TVM_SETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, lparam);
    }
```

What I now want is that I should be able to check any child nodes selected(at runtime) and if any selected I should be able to add the text of selected child node in to an array list(since multiple checkboxes can be selected) and if none selected message box appears as none selected.

Before hiding the parent checkboxes,when I tried the code below, it worked fine..But now(after hiding the parent checkboxes) this doesn't work..

```
public void checkednodes()
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in taskslctor_treeview.Nodes)
        {               
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                check.Add(node.Text);
                MessageBox.Show(check.ToString());
            }
        }
        if (check.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Atleast one task needs to be selected!!", "Error");
        }
    }
```

Any immediate help would be really appreciated...since my work is on hold now..

Comment: Your `Level-1 nodes` don't have any `CheckBoxes` so you can't use the `Checked` properties, What actually do you want? You want to check the `Checked` of the child nodes? As I said, the `Level-1 nodes` **don't have** any `CheckBoxes`, the `Checked` property is useless on them.

Comment: @KingKing:So, no other way to check for any selected child nodes and get their corresponding text??

Comment: check out my answer to get the solution, if it's not, leave some comment so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, looks like you just need to check the `child nodes`, not the `level-1 node`, so this should work for you:

```
//Use this to get all the Checked child nodes under a Parent node
private List<TreeNode> GetCheckedNodes(TreeNode node){
  List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
  if(node.Checked) nodes.Add(node);
  foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
    nodes.AddRange(GetCheckedNodes(n));
  return nodes;
}


 check.Clear();
 foreach (TreeNode node in taskslctor_treeview.Nodes) {               
    foreach(TreeNode childNode in GetCheckedNodes(node)){
        check.Add(childNode.Text);            
    }
 }
 MessageBox.Show(check.ToString());
 if (check.Count == 0){
    MessageBox.Show("Atleast one task needs to be selected!!", "Error");
 }
```

### UPDATE

To get both `Checked` and `Unchecked` nodes, you should declare 2 `List<TreeNode>` which stores the nodes respectively, then you just need a `recursive` loop to fill the 2 lists, like this:

```
List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
List<TreeNode> uncheckedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
private void FillNodeLists(TreeNode node){
  if(node.Checked) checkedNodes.Add(node);
  else uncheckedNodes.Add(node);
  foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
     FillNodeLists(n);
}
//then just use the 2 Lists (such as loop through them)
```

Comment: Thanks..Brilliant!!!
This works fine...But I could see the text of selected checkboxes getting repeated in the arraylist.
Suppose if I have selected 3 checkboxes, then in my thinking, arraylist size should be upto3(from 0 to 2),but when I give the 4th index to print it print the same result of 0 itself.Why it is so??

Comment: @vysakh maybe you've tried it multi-times continuously, you need to clear the `check` before adding new Text each time.

Comment: Else, I would like to do as when I click a button I should be able to disable all the other checkboxes(which is not selected by the user at the runtime)..Is this possible?

Comment: @vysakh see my update for a little modified code which works better than 2 separate methods (one for getting checked nodes and one for getting unchecked nodes)

Comment: Not like this..I have asked like when I click a button, it should disable all the checkboxes which are not selected at that moment..Is this possible??

Comment: @vysakh **It's possible**, but it's too much code here. You should ask in another question such as `How to disable a TreeNode`... The difficulty is to mimic the `Disabled look of the CheckBox`, if your `TreeNode` doesn't have `CheckBox`, we can do it in a simpler way.

Comment: But I dont think that is possible since the user has to select the option needed for them...Any way I will ask as another question..

Thanks for this..